# Why is my Sieve of Eratosthenes removing the non-prime numbers?

Tags: python, sieve-of-eratosthenes

My code:

```
def sieve(list1):

    not_prime = set()
    primes = []
    for i in range(2, list1+1):
        if i in not_prime:
            continue
        for x in range(i*2, list1+1, i):
            not_prime.add(x)
        primes.append(i)
    return primes
```

I am trying to keep the non-prime numebrs and change it to 0. Where am I going wrong? The output doesn't even show any other number besides the prime numbers.

Comment: "I am trying to KEEP the even numbers" - but except for 2, they're not prime. Why do you want to keep them?

Comment: Where do you "change it to 0"?

Comment: Sorry. I meant to say non-prime numbers. Not evens.

Comment: The non-prime numbers go in `not_prime`, and `primes` just contains the prime numbers. That's the whole point. What's the problem?

Comment: Where do you use the values you are appending to the `not_prime` set?

Comment: I am trying to change the code so I can just replace the numbers that are not prime to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Well in that case, cant you just append zero instead of continue in the no_prime clause?

```
def sieve(list1):
    not_prime = set()
    primes = []
    for i in range(2, list1+1):
        if i in not_prime:
            primes.append(0);
            continue;
        for x in range(i*2, list1+1, i):
            not_prime.add(x)
        primes.append(i)
    return primes



sieve(27)

# output [2, 3, 0, 5, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 13, 0, 0, 0, 17, 0, 19, 0, 0, 0, 23, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Or if this is anything beyond a toy, you probably want to look into sparse arrays.

Comment: I originally did that, but for some reason the numbers are repeated. So I thought there might be another way.

Comment: Edited to add back missing continue; statement.

Comment: Jkim, I am afraid it isn't very clear what you are trying to achieve, and what you want the stack overflow community to help you with here. Perhaps you could add some further explanation and expected output to your question